# In mongoDb, how can I rename a field nested like object-> object -> array -> object -> field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nested

Sounds messy,  I know.
The document I'm modifying is structured like this:

```
{
   "_id":12345,
   "name":"harold",
   "basicData":{
      "devices":[
         {
            "id":7654,
            "relatedJson":{
               "make":"sony",
               "equipmentID":"asdf"
            }
         },
         {
            "id":9493
         }
      ],
      "car":"toyota"
   }
}
```

I can't quite get the code right. This is what I have:

```
db.serviceAgreement.updateMany({"basicData.devices.relatedJson.equipmentID": {$exists: true}},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "basicData.devices": {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$basicData.devices", in: {
                            $mergeObjects: ["$$this.relatedJson",
                                {equipmentId: "$$this.relatedJson.equipmentID",}]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $unset: "basicData.devices.relatedJson.equipmentID"
        }

    ])
```

So my understanding of this script is that I'm calling `$set` to set the field `basicData.devices`, then I'm setting it to that same list, but before I do that I'm merging the documents `relatedJson` and a new document `{equipmentId : "$$this.relatedJson.equipmentID",}` which has the value `equipmentId` set to the same value as the `equipmentID` in the `relatedJson` object.
Then, I'm replacing the `relatedJson` document with the newly created `equipmentId` (not my intention).
And finally, deleting the original `equipmentID` - which doesn't actually exist any more because I've replaced the whole `relatedJson` object.

How can I insert the new `equipmentId` into the `relatedJson` object, instead of replacing it entirely.

I have tried variations of the above script that do all sorts of things, inserting a copy of `relatedJson` into itself, inserting a copy of `devices` into `relatedJson`, deleting everything inside `devices`, but I can't get it to do what I want.
I feel I'm close to a solution, and maybe I need to modify the `$input:` but I can't figure out how, or maybe my approach is totally wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The end result should be the same document, but `relatedJson.equipmentID` should be renamed `relatedJson.equipmentId` (with a lower-case 'd' at the end);

Comment: can you add what is your expected output? I'm not sure I understood it

Comment: I want to rename `relatedJson.equipmentID` to `relatedJson.equipmentId` (lower case 'd' at the end) so the document should remain the same except for that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just had some syntax issues.

The update should look like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({"basicData.devices.relatedJson.equipmentID": {$exists: true}},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "basicData.devices": {
        $map: {
          input: "$basicData.devices",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $ne: [
                      "$$this.relatedJson",
                      undefined
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    relatedJson: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this.relatedJson",
                        {
                          equipmentId: "$$this.relatedJson.equipmentID"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "basicData.devices.relatedJson.equipmentID"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6e66ln2A2d6)

Comment: So you're adding a condition saying if the document is !=  relatedJson then do nothing? (I'll google all this later, just curious if my interpretation is right).

Comment: Basically yes.and obviously the additional syntax changes.

Comment: Hi again, I'm having trouble getting my head around how the `$cond` and `$ne` part of the script works. The way I'm understanding it is like `$cond[ <boolean condition>, <do if true>, <do if false>]` but then the `$ne` part I'm not getting, does it say "if serviceAgreementStatus is not equal to undefined" ? The mongodb docs don't explain that syntax you are using. Any chance you could explain it?

Comment: Yes, essentially if "relatedJson" does not exist ( like the in the second device in your sample ) i don't want to create an empty object for it. so basically i tell the "$cond" if this object does not exists just merge with the empty object `{}`. specifically the `$ne` part just tells mongo if this field is not undefined meaning "relatedJson" exists, it's basically a way to replace the "$exists" operator which is not part of the aggregation expression language.

Comment: Thank you! You've helped my understanding of these scripts immensely! I've had a lot of trouble getting my head around this stuff.

Comment: If I wanted to update the `$cond` function to exclude objects/fields with a value set to `null` too, how can I do that? I've come across a situation where if for example `relatedJson` is `null`,  then the script sets it to an empty object (obviously because we're merging it with a new `relatedJson` object), which is problematic for me.